# Data not rendering in html file after async call

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm calling an api which returns a response data about a single blog post. But It's not rendering in the html page. This code returns a console error like

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined
>       at Object.updateRenderer (post.component.html:3)

but I tried with `safe-navigation` like `blogpost?.content.rendered` and `blogpost?.content?.rendered`, both didn't threw any console errors but it didn't render the data as well. What am I doing wrong here?

In both scenario, `{{blogpost | json}}` this works but `innerHTML` doesn't work

**service**

```
getPost(slug: string): Observable<PostRawModel> {
  const url = 'https://blog.varanjith.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=' + slug;
  return this.http.get<PostRawModel>(url);
}
```

**controller**

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  post$: Observable<PostRawModel>;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private blogService: BlogService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        this.post$ = this.blogService.getPost(params.get('slug'));
    });
  }
}
```

**view**

```
<div *ngIf="(post$ | async) as blogpost">
  {{blogpost | json}}
  <div [innerHTML]="blogpost.content.rendered"></div>
</div>
```

**Update #1**

I didn't paste the json data because it'll make this post a mess so
please click the link to see the json data. https://blog.varanjith.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=merging-two-observables-using-forkjoin

**Update #2**

I'm creating a stackblitz now, will update this question with a running code.

Comment: Can you show the blogpost json data

Comment: this is my api, https://blog.varanjith.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=merging-two-observables-using-forkjoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blogpost` is an array, to access the objects within it you need to use the *appropriate* index :

```
blogpost[0].content.rendered
```